# Can you filter data on a retrieved relationship without creating a new attribute?

Tags: php, laravel

I have `one to many` relationship between `users` and `posts`.

I want to know if I eager load in the posts can I modify the collection without a new attribute getting created on the `User` model.

```
$user = User::with('posts')->get();

// Filter the posts on the user using business logic.
// Below is an example. I DO NOT want to do this logic in the db/query builder.

// Arbitrary business rule that is not easily possible to calculate in DB
$shouldGetTestPost = true;

$user->posts = $user->posts->filter(function($post) use ($shouldGetTestPost) {
    if ($shouldGetTestPost && $post->name = 'test') {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
});

dd($user);
```

If I run the above code laravel will create a new attribute called `posts` and assign the collection to that attribute instead of modifying the relationship.

e.g.

```
// I've removed irrelevant model data
App\User {#1145
  #table: "users"
  #attributes: array:6 [
    "id" => 1
    "email" => "test@test.com"
    "password" => "secret"
    "updated_at" => "2019-02-11 18:56:35"
    "created_at" => "2019-02-11 18:56:35"
    // Below is new
    "posts" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1217
      #items: array:1 [
        0 => App\Post {#1269
          #table: "posts"
          #attributes: array:24 [
            "id" => 1
            "name" => 'test'
            "user_id" => 1
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
  #original: array:5 [...]
  #relations: array:1 [
    "posts" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1264
      #items: array:2 [
        0 => App\Post {#1269}
        1 => App\Post {#1234
          #table: "posts"
          #attributes: array:24 [
            "id" => 1
            "name" => 'test'
            "user_id" => 1
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
]
```

Another interesting thing that happens is that in `#relations` the data is removed from the`items` array but the reference still remains. See `0 => App\Post {#1269}`

Is this intended for laravel? I'm aware that laravel prioritises attributes over relations but it seems odd that it wouldn't change the relations array.

How would I only change the relations collection and not create a new attribute?

Comment: Why would you be wanting to change the loaded relations array?  Can you describe your actual problem instead of your attempted solution so we don't have an XY problem here.

Comment: @Devon It's a business logic reason that is not stored in the database.

Comment: That's not a very descriptive answer.  Why wouldn't you add your conditions to the relationship method or constrain the eager loading instead of loading all the data and filtering it afterwards?

Comment: The same reason you would apply logic to a collection after you have retrieved the data. I'll change the code to clarify.

Comment: Updated my code to clarify.

Comment: That still doesn't answer the latter.  Why not constrain the eager loading based on the business logic instead?  If you only need 10 records, why load 100 and then filter it down to 10 instead of just loading the 10 you need to begin with?

Comment: The real query is around 100 lines long. The situation I'm in is I need to filter relation data after the query is completed. The question I'm asking here is why when you filter on a relation an attribute is created?

Comment: Yeah, my answer should work for you, but I still don't think your solution makes any sense.  Without knowing more about your problem, I can't help you, beyond telling you that you shouldn't be using setRelation or trying to set a relationship attribute.

Comment: Yup no worries. It's just an obscure situation that I didn't want to get into. It isn't relevant to what I actually want to do / know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setRelation method can be used to override what's stored in a relation.

```
$model->setRelation($relation, $value)
```

https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasRelationships.html#method_setRelation

However, there's very few situations where this would be useful so I still believe this is an XY problem.   You can [constrain the eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads) query by passing a closure as the second argument to `with()` which would be the solution to conditionally retrieving related items.